# 3 variable chart in excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010

I am trying to come up with a best way to represent 3 variables via excel chart. I am unable to figure out how to create such chart. Ideally, I would like to have product on x-axis, revenue on y-axis and revenue on each product on chart. But I am open for ideas. Here is the data.

```
+---------+----------+---------+--+--+
| Product | Quantity | Revenue |  |  |
+---------+----------+---------+--+--+
| A       | 200      | 23500   |  |  |
+---------+----------+---------+--+--+
| B       | 300      | 55000   |  |  |
+---------+----------+---------+--+--+
| C       | 800      | 11000   |  |  |
+---------+----------+---------+--+--+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a combination chart with columns for Quantity and a line for Revenue, or vice versa. Plot one series on the secondary axis, so you can have different scales on the same chart.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for dumb question, but do you have steps to do this?

Comment: The exact steps differ between the versions of Excel. Glad you found how it works for you.